# Drop some values from numpy array to reshape them properly?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape `(231250, 19)`, when i try to reshape it into `(-1,1000,19)`, it gives me error. `cannot reshape array of size 4393750 into shape (1000,19)`. Reason is that my numpy array cannot be completed divisible. `4393750/19/1000` give me answer with decimal points. 
What i want is to remove some elements from numpy array, so that it should be completely reshaped.  if i remove 4750 elemts from my array, i can reshape my array

Each time the rows of array is different, so i am unable to think a generic solution.
Please help me to solve this  .

I have come up with this solution

```
shape=data.ravel().shape[0]
s=shape%19000
if s!=0:
    d=data.ravel()[s//2:-s//2].reshape(-1,1000,19)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexing to drop the modulo:

```
org_size = 231250
new_size = 1000
a = np.ones((org_size, 19))[: org_size - org_size % new_size, :].reshape((-1, new_size, 19))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Apply `floor` >> `indexing` >> `reshaping` to achieve what you are looking for.

```py
rows, cols = data.shape
rows = int(floor(rows/1000))
d = data[:rows,:].reshape((-1,rows,cols))
d.shape
```

Answer (score 0):

It's cleaner to delete entire rows instead of random elements here and there

```
a = np.zeros((231250, 19))
>>>rows, columns = a.shape
(231250, 19)

>>>4750/19
250
```

We will randomly select 250 rows and delete them

```
delete_rows = np.random.randint(rows, size=(250, 1))
a = np.delete(a, delete_rows, axis=0)
```

Now we can reshape our array

```
b = a.reshape(-1,1000,19)
```